# Creating an applet to get an image

Tags: java

Is there anything wrong with doing this:

```
public static Image getPicture01()
{
    Applet app = new Applet();
    Image t = app.getImage(app.getClass().getResource("/res/pic01.png"));
    return t;
}
```

My goal is to get a resource (image) from my project in Java, and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong with doing this:...

Yes, it is totally unnecessary, wasteful (creating an unneeded object, Applet), and there are better alternatives -- ImageIO.read(...) for one.